# A connection between prime PINs and generalized triangular numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recurrence-relations

I noticed that my PIN is a non-decreasing sequence of primes, $3337$ (don't worry, that's not the real one), and I wondered how many such PINs there are. That is, if $p_i\in\{2,3,5,7\}$ and $p_i\leq p_{i+1}$, how many different PINS $p_1p_2p_3p_4$ can one make? $35,$ it turns out. The list goes:
$$2222$$
$$2223$$
$$\vdots$$
$$5777$$
$$7777$$

Let's generalize the problem:

> If $a_i\in\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ and $a_i\leq a_{i+1},$ how many different sequences $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are there?

Let this number be $T^k_n.$ For the first few, we have

\begin{align}
T^1_n&=1\\
T^2_n&=n+1\\
T^3_n&=T_{n+1}\\
T^4_n&=Te_{n+1},
\end{align}
where $T_{n+1}$ is the $(n+1)$th [triangular number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangularNumber.html) and $Te_{n+1}$ is the $(n+1)$th [tetrahedral number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TetrahedralNumber.html).

It seems that 
$$T^{k+1}_n=1+\sum_{i=1}^nT_i^k.$$

**Can we find a closed-form expression for $T^k_n$?**

Also, do these numbers have a known name? I imagine that they could be interpreted as a generalization of triangular numbers to higher dimensions, with the tetrahedral numbers being the first step above (going from two dimensions to three).

I found [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27956867) funny little paper from '63, but it doesn't seem to address this problem directly (perhaps it does, and I just don't realize it).

Comment: You didn't give your PIN number, but you narrowed down the guess time by a factor of $30$... :D

Comment: Your PIN number is nondecreasing sequence, not increasing.

Comment: Any multiset chosen from the fixed set can be arranged in non-decreasing order in a unique way.

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak Thanks, edited.

Comment: @5xum Yeah, I know, but sometimes you gotta live dangerously! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve this using stars and bars. An example on $n=k=4$ (the PIN example) i.e. you have four numbers:

$$* * * *$$

And you put $3$ bars in between. After each bar, the number jumps up by one. So, for example,

$$*|*|*|*$$

would mean the number $2357$ and $$||**|**$$ represents $$5577$$

So the number we are talking about is $$\left({5\choose3}\right) = {{5+3-1}\choose 3} = {7\choose 3} = 35$$

---

In general, you want to write out $n+1$ bars and $k$ stars, which means the number you are looking for is $$\left({{n+1}\choose k}\right)$$

Comment: Do you have any insight into the geometrical interpretation of this problem? I mentioned the "higher-dimensional" triangular numbers. Can $T_n^k$`perhaps be interpreted as the number of balls stacked in a $(k-1)$-simplex?